# Using Webservice and json parse to make a ranking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

I'm new to objective-c and trying to learn somethings.

I'm creating a sprite-kit game and a online ranking using a webservice with php.

right now, I just need to get a json that returns the top 10 names/scores.

I'm doing this:

NSMutableArray* nomes;
    NSMutableArray* scores;

```
NSData* jsonDados = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                     [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.420blazeitswag.com/wsGame/functions.php?funcao=getRanking"]];


NSError *error;

NSMutableDictionary *jsonRanking = [NSJSONSerialization
                                    JSONObjectWithData:jsonDados
                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                    error:&error];
NSDictionary* ranking = [jsonRanking objectForKey:@"ranking"];

resultado = [NSMutableArray alloc];
nomes = [ranking objectForKey:@"NOME"];
scores = [ranking objectForKey:@"SCORE"];

NSLog(@"count: %lu\n",[ranking count]);

for(int i=0;i<[ranking count];i++){
     [resultado addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nomes[i],@"nome",scores[i],@"score", nil]];
    NSLog(@"Nome: %@ Score: %@",nomes[i],scores[i]);
}
```

As soon I execute this code, I get a "CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)" message, and a lot more because of it.

What should I do?
Thanks since now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
NSDictionary* ranking = [jsonRanking objectForKey:@"ranking"];
```

is incorrect because the value for key `"ranking"` will be an `NSArray`. Inside that array you then have a number of dictionaries. So, you need to iterate the 'ranking' array and process each of the dictionaries individually.

Looking at your code though, the only different between `resultado` and the JSON you get back (so the content of `ranking` is the capitalisation of the keys so you might not need to do any iteration at all...

Start with:

```
NSArray *ranking = [jsonRanking objectForKey:@"ranking"];
```

It isn't clear why you get an SSL error message as the JSON you're loading is coming from an `http` site and there doesn't seem to be any redirection. You need to be sure where the SSL error message is coming from before that can be resolved.

Aside:

Don't just do: `[NSMutableArray alloc]`. Always call an `init` method after you call `alloc`. If you don't want to do `alloc init`, use a class convenience method instead (like `[NSMutableArray array]`).

Comment: I understand that "ranking" is a NSArray now, but, how could I change my code to it? Sorry for my "dumbness", I'm having a hard time trying to understand how it all works.

And, I tried to comment everything below NSData *jsonDados, I still getting this message: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)

What would it be?

Answer (score 2):

```
    NSDictionary* ranking = [jsonRanking objectForKey:@"ranking"];

resultado = [NSMutableArray alloc];
nomes = [ranking objectForKey:@"NOME"];
scores = [ranking objectForKey:@"SCORE"];

NSLog(@"count: %lu\n",[ranking count]);

for(int i=0;i<[rankingList count];i++){
     [resultado addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nomes[i],@"nome",scores[i],@"score", nil]];
    NSLog(@"Nome: %@ Score: %@",nomes[i],scores[i]);
}
```

chang it to

```
NSArray* rankingList = [jsonRanking objectForKey:@"ranking"];
nsstring *name;
nsstring *scores;
for(int i=0;i<[rankingList count];i++){    
NSDictionary* ranking = [rankingList objectAtList:i];
nomes = [ranking objectForKey:@"NOME"];
scores = [ranking objectForKey:@"SCORE"];
NSLog(@"Nome: %@ Score: %@",nomes,scores);
}
```